# CoordinatorLayout causes FrameLayout to fall behind the navigation bar at the bottom

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-support-design, coordinator-layout

This is my activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I replace `frameLayoutContainer` with a ConstraintLayout-rooted Fragment. It has a Button view at the bottom constrained with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

But the Button view falls behind the navigation bar. I have many activities almost the same structure with this, but they don't have such a problem.

When I replace CoordinatorLayout with a LinearLayout, the problem is solved, but I want to know what is wrong with CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Which style did you apply to this activity?

Comment: And one more think, try removing android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from your root layout element.

Answer (score 2):

The line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` does all the job. Try to remove this line from your XML file and you will see that the problem happens even if you do not replace `frameLayoutContainer` with `Fragment`.

Thus, the solution is to add this line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your root of Fragment (either in your XML or programmatically) and check it.

Comment: @Egemen Hamutçu Did you check?